How to retrieve parent id inside child repeater form in filamentphp?
I have three forms created using repeater, requests form which is nested under groups and groups nested under projects (projects -> groups -> requests)
The requests table have fields project_id, group_id, name, etc..., group_id will be auto inserted by repeater but project_id is not inserted automatically because this is a grandparent relation. So, I tried to manually get the project_id from parent but I am not getting the id.
The repeater in Project resource like below,
return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')->required()->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\Textarea::make('description')->columnSpanFull(),

                Forms\Components\Repeater::make('groups')->relationship()->schema([
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')->required(),
                    Forms\Components\Textarea::make('description'),

                    Forms\Components\Repeater::make('requests')->relationship()->schema([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')->required(),
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('type')
                        ->options([
                            'GET' => 'GET',
                            'POST' => 'POST',
                            'DELETE' => 'DELETE',
                            'PATCH' => 'PATCH',
                            'PUT' => 'PUT',
                        ])
                        ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('endpoint')->required()->columnSpanFull(),
                    ])->orderColumn('sort')->collapsible()->columns(2)->columnSpanFull()
                    ->mutateRelationshipDataBeforeCreateUsing(function (array $data, Get $get): array {
                        // $data['project_id'] = $get('../../id');
                        // dd($get);
                        // dd($data);
                        return $data;
                    })
                    ->itemLabel(fn (array $state): ?string => $state['name'] ?? null),
                    
                ])->orderColumn('sort')->collapsible()->columns(2)->columnSpanFull()
                ->itemLabel(fn (array $state): ?string => $state['name'] ?? null),
                
            ]);

From the above code, the projects data is inserted and groups data is inserted. But while inserting requests data I need to provide project_id which is created above.

Here is the answer for the above question.
By using livewire we can make it possible. The updated code,
->mutateRelationshipDataBeforeCreateUsing(function (array $data, $livewire): array {
                        // dd($livewire);
                        $data['project_id'] = $livewire->record->id;
                        return $data;
                    })

